# What is the lifetime in major browsers of user consent for W3C Geolocation API?

Tags: browser, geolocation, lifetime, w3c-geolocation

According to [section 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation/#user-consent) of W3C Geolocation API recommendation:

> An end-user will generally give express permission through a user interface, which usually present a range of permission lifetimes that the end-user can choose from. The choice of lifetimes vary across user agents, but they are typically time-based (e.g., "a day"), or until browser is closed, or the user might even be given the choice for the permission to be granted indefinitely.
>
> [...]
>
> Although the granularity of the permission lifetime varies across user-agents, this specification urges user agents to limit the lifetime to a single browsing session by default (see 3.4 Checking permission to use the API for normative requirements).

Is this recommendation of a single browsing session respected by major browsers? More generally, what are the lifetimes defined by major browsers for geolocation access?